# Time complexity of O(n^2)

Tags: c, complexity-theory

```
void f(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n * n / i; j += i)
            printf(“*”);
}
```

Whats the time complexity for this code?
I figured it would be **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** but turns out the actual answer is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** and I have no clue why.
can someone explain? (there is a chance its a mistake in the exam)

Comment: The inner loop isn't n^2. You divided it `n*n/i`

Comment: Technically, it's O(n³), but also O(n²) ;)

Comment: You probably shouldn't care since the code contains `printf` and it's by far the most massive bottleneck in this code. In general I'd recommend to study real world performance of real programs, not theoretical big ohs of fictional programs.

Comment: yea im studying in a university so the printf there is not the point of the code. imagine that printf was just a ;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things to notice about the inner loop:

1. The "divide by `i`" here: `j<=n*n/i`
2. The "increment by `i`" here: `j+=i` (which gives another "divide by `i`)

Taking that into account we can see how many time the inner loop executes depending of the value of `i`:

```
i = 1 --> n*n/1/1

i = 2 --> n*n/2/2

i = 3 --> n*n/3/3

i = 4 --> n*n/4/4

....
```

Then make the sum:

```
n*n/1/1 + n*n/2/2 + n*n/3/3 + n*n/4/4 + ...
```

which is:

```
n*n/1^2 + n*n/2^2 + n*n/3^2 + n*n/4^2 + ...
```

which is:

```
n^2 * (1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + 1/4^2 + ... )
```

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem this is approx:

```
n^2 * 1.644934
```

so **the complexity is O(n^2)**

Just for fun the following code calculates the number of times the inner loop is executed

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long  f(int n)
{
    unsigned long long c = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=n*n/i; j+=i)
        {
            ++c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void g(int n)
{
    unsigned long long c = f(n);
    printf("d=%-10d c=%-10llu c/n^2=%f\n", n, c, (((double)c)/n/n));
}

int main()
{
    g(10);
    g(100);
    g(1000);
    g(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
d=10         c=157        c/n^2=1.570000
d=100        c=16395      c/n^2=1.639500
d=1000       c=1644474    c/n^2=1.644474
d=10000      c=164488783  c/n^2=1.644888
```

Comment: According to WolfamAlpha, the constant is: 1.29128. Indeed, the Wikipedia page that you linked reports a different formula

Comment: But probably is just the wrong formula, it should be: `n*n * (1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + 1/4^2 + ... )`

Comment: Its always  n^2/i^2 I got that, but isnt this sum O(n^3)?

Comment: I got it finally thank you

Comment: @RavidOfek if an answer solved your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as the acceptable answer (and also consider to give it an upvote).